# How can I return a string with double quotes to a client script parse it into JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, json, escaping

I have a WebMethod that is called by JavaScript to get data from a database. The database is off limits for this, so I can't change anything there. I'd like to do this in JavaScript.

The string looks like this when it gets to the JavaScript:

```
"[{"id":"0", "value":"Avery Bradley"},{"id":"31", "value":"Jason "Jet" Terry"}]"
```

I've tried replacing `('\"', '\\\"')` to add in an escape character. I got it to work on the .NET side that way `Replace("\"", "\\\"")`. However, this is a self contained control that will be using it and that validation should be there.

What am I doing wrong?

function GetDataCallBack(childId, senderParam, senderValue, callback) {
    var values;

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: callback,
    data: "{'id': '" + childId + "', 'parameter': '" + senderParam + "', 'value': '" + senderValue + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (json) {
        values = json.d;
    }
});
return values;
```

}

Comment: So what is between the database and the javascript? IS there some sort of API that can be modified to return properly encoded JSON?

Comment: can you show us the javascript code that is getting this string? That may help let us see what can be done.

Comment: @MikeBrant The control will be used in multiple products. I wanted to encode it in JS so it wouldn't have to be added to each webservice it calls to.

Comment: @Yatrix So you are expecting all the web services you are calling to you return mal-formed JSON?  That is kind of a weird assumption to make. I would start with the assumption that you would get properly formed JSON and fix those web services where you are not getting it or customize your JSON response handling only for those services.

Comment: @MikeBrant Maybe I'm thinking about it wrong then. I just thought it best to have the validation encapsulated in the control, but I guess it should be able to expect valid date input into it to work. Thanks.

Comment: @Yatrix I don't think it is wrong at all to validate that you have correctly formed JSON before continuing the process on the client. I just personally wouldn't try to FIX the invalid JSON at the client. It should be fixed on the server IMO.

Comment: @MikeBrant Makes perfect sense. I'll hit them with a rude alert - that'll show 'em.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on the server side. It's serving invalid JSON.  Specifically, this inside the last object in the array:

```
"value":"Jason "Jet" Terry"
```

Those quotes around `"Jet"` need to be escaped. The server is giving you invalid JSON.

You can try to correct broken JSON, but it will be kludgy and likely imperfect.

The server side needs to be fixed so that it serves valid JSON.

Comment: This seems like the way to go, from what I'm seeing. I'm new to client/server architecture, so I supposed the way I was thinking about this was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing something wrong here. A JSON file should be just JSON and nothing else. It should not be a string representation of JSON, which is string-parsed into a string and from there parsed to an Object - just treat the file/stream/whatever as the string.

If you need to embed the JSON into some markup (XML, HTML), use the designated escape methods for that language on the JSON string.

If you need to embed the JSON into some program file, try to use a matching literal representation of the encoded objects (very easy in Javascript, for example). If you use a language that has no good representation, store it into an extra text file and read it from there.

Comment: I am getting data from a database through a webservice call and creating a string to pass back to the calling JavaScript. How would I go about doing that without creating a string to pass back?

Comment: Yes, return a string of JSON. Don't string-escape the JSON string.

Comment: I'm confused. How do I go about that? I'm a web noob, sorry.